# Need references: Auto code generator C++

Tags: c++, code-generation, reference

I need to create a Auto code generator that generates Fortran codes and implemented on either C or C++.

Can anyone give me some references or a good place to start this... Even any suggestion or ideas too....

Comment: You should precise what kind of code you want to generate, if its a translation of another program, if it's generated from scratch, ...

Comment: I don't have a source code.. So, I am not translating any code.. So I guess it is not a compiler.. something like ATLAS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatically_Tuned_Linear_Algebra_Software)

Comment: Use your favorite search engine and search for "fortran translator", "compiler construction" and "compiler dragon book".

Answer (score 1):

This is called a compiler. Anything that translates from one language to another is a compiler. I suggest you read up on compilers.

Comment: No, this does not sound like a compiler.  For example, `m4` is a macro substitution language, no one would call it a compiler.  Yet it outputs source code.  Same with the C preprocessor.  Same with a zillion other template engines.

Comment: I didn't think in that way, may be its just like compiler, but actually I don't have the source code. I need to generate some code... I am not actually translating the code...

Comment: Sounds more like a *translator*, rather than a *compiler*.  A translator will convert FORTRAN into C or C++ source code.  A compiler will generate an executable, no need to convert FORTRAN to C then to executable.

Comment: I repeat: anything that translates from one language to another is a compiler. If you compile C, it doesn't go straight to 0's and 1's, it goes to assembly which is... another language. And from that it goes to 0's and 1's, which (believe it or not) is still another language.

Comment: It's only a compiler if it parses and lexes the source code and performs syntactic analysis including such things as overload resolution according to the rules of the source language.  Simple string substitution is not compiling.  And even if you choose to call it a compiler instead of a code generator, your recommendation to study compiler theory is not helpful, since things like type analysis that are very important to most compilers, aren't to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Good starting places:

```
#include <string.h>
```

(for C)

```
#include <sstream>
```

(for C++)

Comment: `#include <sstream>`, actually, though I don't see what it has to do with the question.

Comment: @Neil: This question mostly involves a lot of string concatenation.